# Kendo draggable: change dragged item after dragstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, draggable

in my WebApp I use a Kendo ListView where each item is a draggable to move events inside a Kendo Scheduler to register them.

The items in the ListView have this template:

```
<div class="move myDivClass" myOtherAttributes="myOtherAttributes>
 <span class="mySpanClass">NUMBER</span>
</div>
```

And I make them Kendo Draggables with this code:

```
tempList.kendoDraggable({
  filter: ".move",
  dragstart: function (e) {
    //my code
    $("#hint").css("margin-left", e.clientX - $(e.initialTarget).offset().left - 20);
  },
    hint: function (row, event) {
    //remove old selection
    row.parent().find(".k-state-selected").each(function(){$(this).removeClass("k-state-selected") });
    row.addClass("k-state-selected");
    var hintElement = row.clone();
    hintElement.attr("id", "hint");
    hintElement.width(40).height(40);
    return hintElement;
  }
});
```

My problem is if I drag my item by pressing the mouse button while over the number inside the item, when I drop on the scheduler it doesn't get saved, because of various reason. (It took me a long time to understand the problem was with that span!)

I even came up with some kind of a solution, by adding this propriety to my KendoDraggables

```
ignore: "span"
```

The problem with this solution is if I press the mouse button while over the number, I will get a "plain text" selection, not the drag.
And that makes sense, since I exclude that element from the draggables.

So, to make this work properly, I think there are some things I could do:

- Write said number in a different way, so that if I click on the number it doesn't get selected at all
- If inside dragstart, by checking the referenced event "e", I notice the dragged element is a span, change the dragged element to the parent of said span

But I don't know ho to do this. So I guess the questions are:

- Is there a way to write the number inside that box so it won't be a target, but what is behind it could remain a target?
- If in the dragstart i change all the references to the initial target to the parent item, will it work? Is there a way to systematically do this instead of looking for all the fields containing said element?

Answer (score 0):

Oh damn, just found the right solution :)
I will simply remove the span and put the number directly inside the div.

Dumb me.